# correctly rebase a merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Another git question... I am in the following situation:

```
A1 ---- B1 ---- C1
                   \
                    > D ---- E ---- F
                   /
A2 ---- B2 ---- C2
```

Where {A1,B1,C1} and {A2,B2,C2} have *no* files in common (it's the consequence of merging two different repositories, so I have currently two roots)

I would like the history to look like this

```
A1 ---- B1 ---- C1 ---- A2 ---- B2 ---- C2 ---- D ---- E --- F
```

But I cannot figure out how to do that with git-rebase, any idea?

Bonus: If I can keep the tags (which I have on all three branches) without having to do it manually...

Comment: Did you try to use the interactive mode?

Comment: I know what interactive mode is, but I just cannot find what I should give to rebase so that he does what I want..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following two commands, in sequence:

```
git filter-branch -f --parent-filter 'test $GIT_COMMIT = <a2> && echo "-p <c1>" || cat'
git filter-branch -f --parent-filter 'test $GIT_COMMIT = <new head> && echo "-p <c2>" || cat'
```

Of course, you have to replace `<a2>`, `<c1>`, `<new head>` etc. by the corresponding commit hashes. Note that the head's hash changes after the first command, which is why I called it `<new head>` instead of just `<d>`.

It's actually pretty straightforward: the first command sets C1 as A2's parent. The second command fixes the graph by setting C2 as D's only parent.

Comment: Your answer is short and effective. I like mine in the sense that it gave me a new understanding in the way git works, but now that I learned that yours is no doubt far better :)

Comment: (by the way I see that you answered my question before me, but I'm glad I didn't see it before I found my solution otherwise I wouldn't have looked further)

Comment: Yeah, playing around with git is always good for understanding. I learned stuff from your answer at well, for example I didn't know `git replace`, seems useful! Vice versa I'm also glad that I didn't read your answer before finding my solution. Same reason as yours :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out a way to do that. Since it gives a big up in the understanding of the internals of git, I give a detailed answer here:

First, you have to give to A2 a new parent, since it didn't have before:

```
git cat-file commit A2
```

produces a summary where no "parent appear". So create the line, and create a new hash:

```
git cat-file commit A2 | sed -e '2aparent C1' | git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
```

This will give a hash {H1} as an output, that we use to replace A2 by this new hash:

```
git replace A2 H1
```

And voila, the A2 has now C1 as parent. But now the history looks like that:

```
A1 ---- B1 ---- C1 --------------------- D ----- E ----- F
                  \                     /
                     A2 ---- B2 ---- C2
```

So do the same to D, which has two parents (C1 and C2):

```
git cat-file commit D
```

Remove the "parent" line corresponding to C1, and hash, and replace:

```
H2=`git cat-file commit D | sed -e '/parent C1/d' | git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin`
git replace D H2
```

It looks like it worked for me. If I understand well what I did, this worked well because I had different files on both repositories. I think things could get wrong if I had files common in both repositories that were merged in a way in D.